# How to extract the Bearer token from an API response and pass it to the header of other API in Taurus?

Tags: jmeter, web-api-testing, taurus

I have an API endpoint named `generateAccessToken` which will generate an `accessToken` and it will send the access token with the response.

*Response of `generateAccessToken` API:*

```
{
"data": {
   "userId": "sdfjojeit8hg48ut39h3hr89",
   "accessToken": "fjwem9t3e435ttu3t9u298ywt89gnm389ncr2x99829mntcmx" 
  }
}
```

And there is another API endpoint named `getUserProfile` which will fetch the user profile and return the response. This endpoint needs the `accessToken` in the `Bearer` header.

The header of the `getUserProfile` API:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer fjwem9t3e435ttu3t9u298ywt89gnm389ncr2x99829mntcmx
```

And there are many similar APIs that will require `accessToken` in the `Authentication` header.

I need to test these APIs with a single `yml` file.

The test need to hit the `generateAccessToken` API and *fetch* the `accessToken` from the response of the `generateAccessToken` API and store it in a variable and other variables will add this variable to its `Authorization` header.

I'm able to do this with `Jmeter` using `JsonExtractor` and `HTTPHeaderManager`

I'm new to `Taurus` and quiet confused how to configure `yml` file to do this.
so far, I have created this one. But not sure how to store and use `accessToken` in header.

```
execution:
  - concurrency: 100
    ramp-up: 1m
    hold-for: 2m
    scenario: TestUser

scenarios:
  TestUser:
    requests:
      - url: 'https://mywebapplication.com/generateAccessToken'
        method: POST
        headers:
          Content-Type: 'application/json'
      - url: 'https://mywebapplication.com/user/profile'
        method: GET
        headers:
          Content-Type: 'application/json'
          Authorization: 'kjdfoejgejfoskdfoeieio4etg94gn4880'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For particular your case Taurus doesn't add any value, it will just create additional overhead so given you have a working JMeter script you can just [run in in JMeter's command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode) or if you need certain Taurus feature like real-time reporting you can [run the existing JMeter .jmx test](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Run-Existing-JMX-File) script using Taurus as:

```
bzt /path/to/your/test.jmx
```

If for any reason you still want to implement this scenario in [Taurus YAML](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/) - take a look at **Extractors** chapter of Taurus manual. You should be able to get what you want by amending your test as follows:

```
execution:
  - concurrency: 100
    ramp-up: 1m
    hold-for: 2m
    scenario: TestUser

scenarios:
  TestUser:
    requests:
      - url: 'https://mywebapplication.com/generateAccessToken'
        method: POST
        headers:
          Content-Type: 'application/json'
        extract-jsonpath:
          token:
            jsonpath: $.data.accessToken
      - url: 'https://mywebapplication.com/user/profile'
        method: GET
        headers:
          Content-Type: 'application/json'
          Authorization: 'Bearer ${token}'
```

Comment: Thanks man. I have already found these extractors on the documentation and it worked. Anyways, I'll accept this answer as it is the same approach that is used in the documentation and also be helpful for others.